# Why do the elements inside my VStack inside a HStack still go vertical

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

So basically this is my code.

```
            Text("Melbourne, Victoria")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
            
            Image(systemName: "moon.fill")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 60))
            
            
            Text("Today")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            
            Text("34°C")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                    .padding(.bottom, 550)
                
                Text("Mon 34°C")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(.bottom, 550)
                
                
            }
            
        }
        .background(
            Image("night")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
```

I want to make more of the days in this weather app each with it's on SF Symbol and everything is inside this VStack. And the days and SF symbols are inside a HStack to keep them horizontal. But if I want to put more of those the next time I do it they go next to each other but the symbol goes on top look at this.

[This is the image with only 1 of those days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag1Kn.png)

[And this one is when I put more than 1 but its next to each other when I want them vertically aligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2GhD.png)

[This is the one if I put them in another VStack which makes the SF symbol go above the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gd8S.png)

IS there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `.padding(.bottom, 550)`.

```
Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
    .font(.system(size: 40))
    .padding(.bottom, 550) /// here!
```

It's currently attached to your first `Image`. As a result, the `HStack` is stretched vertically and it appears as though the first `Image` is higher up than second one.

To fix, move both `.padding(.bottom, 550)`s to outside your `HStack`.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a lot of arbitrary values for padding. You should have your layout adapt to various devices, rather than hard-coding that `.bottom` spacing for example.

Working example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text("Melbourne, Victoria")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)

            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "moon.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 60))

                Text("Today")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                Text("34°C")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }

            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .font(.system(size: 40))

                    Text("Mon 34°C")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .font(.system(size: 40))

                    Text("Tue 28°C")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(
            Color(red: 0.34, green: 0.36, blue: 0.71)//Image("night")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Although there is already an outer `VStack`, they are nested `VStack`s because they have different amounts of padding. Multiple views are grouped together, and then those are grouped together with larger paddings to separate them.

## Bonus

#### SF Symbols colors

Use:

```
.renderingMode(.original)
```

Rather than:

```
.foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
```

To color the SF Symbols with the default colors, as shown in the above example.

#### Align days

You can align the days across each `HStack` with a custom alignment guide. Use the following:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    struct LeadingDay: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            context[.leading]
        }
    }

    static let leadingDay = HorizontalAlignment(LeadingDay.self)
}
```

Making the other following changes:

```
VStack(alignment: .leadingDay, spacing: 10) { // <- HERE
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .font(.system(size: 40))

        Text("Mon 34°C")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .alignmentGuide(.leadingDay) { d in // <- HERE
                d[.leading]
            }
    }

    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .font(.system(size: 40))

        Text("Tue 28°C")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .alignmentGuide(.leadingDay) { d in // <- HERE
                d[.leading]
            }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: But how do I put my image of the "night" back because you put the colours there?

Comment: @AirWalks Oh, the image is just commented out in the code so anyone can run & test it. The image is still there in the code, just uncomment it and use it as before.